# Web page loading "zoomed"

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I'm working on developing a mobile site and for whatever reason the page seems to load as if it is zoomed in every single time. I can scale it easily on a touch phone and it looks just about right, but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas of how to prevent this from happening.

I have tested this issue on Android and iPhone and it seems to be happening on both.

This didn't seem to help all except that I was unable to scale after the page loaded

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 minimum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use that :
That block pinch to zoom

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: I'm not against the user zooming, I just don't want the page to zoom in automatically when loaded.

Comment: The initial-scale like that set the zoom at 1.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

Comment: you need to use the comma betweeen rules

Comment: It was worth a shoot, but nope. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following meta, as it sets the page load zoom, rather than blocking the zoom function.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

-Edit-
I didn't actually notice you already had initial-scale=1 in your meta. Try with '1.0' instead, I'm not sure if it will make a difference.